# trigger.io how to know number of reloads available?

Tags: trigger.io

is there any way to show the number of reloads available vs reloads spent per month ? IMHO this is an important data to support capacity planning but surprisingly the UI doesn't seems to show it anywhere.

regards

Comment: I can remember it has been there once, but cannot find it right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this information from the status page on any app in the Toolkit.